# Recommended location to add whole-house water filter?

Tags: plumbing, water-filtration

I’m trying to add a spin down sediment filter and one for chlorine. Recommendation to where to break into the plumbing? I’d prefer not using filter on water that is goes out of outdoor hoses. The chlorine filter doesn’t require electricity and needs to stand upright in the floor.

[image: main water line]

Comment: So tap in after the split off to the outdoor lines.  You only show us one photo of your incoming line, but you say there are multiple outdoor lines.  Do we assume all of the outdoor lines come off the same split line?

Comment: @huesman , yes at least to my knowledge the outdoor line is that smaller line to the left just aftre the pressure relief valve. I think it goes to the spigot to the side front and then wraps around the perimeter to the one in the back.

Comment: The chlorine filter makes sense to put after. The spin-down makes sense to put BEFORE the split off of the hose supply. The more flow, the better it works.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, I’ll consider but now that’s an additional cut in main.

Answer (score 1):

An expert on the spin down filter, ( my wife, the GM of a company that manufactured the filters  for 30 years.), has said the best location is just after the line comes into the house.  The Chlorine filter after that.

If your outdoor lines split right after the main comes in , you can add the filters after that. Definitely before the split to HW tank.